# How to do arithmetic on a contextual filter

Tags: views

Rather than specifying a contextual filter, is it possible to specify a contextual filter +1 (i.e. add one to the current filter value?)

If you have a view taking an argument, i understand that you can create a global text field to make a link to a different view using the original argument.

I.e. in view1/arg1 i can have a global text field which outputs as a link to
view2/arg1

Is it possible to create a global text field which outputs as a link to view2/arg1+1

i.e. adds one to the current argument?

Answer (score 1):

In Views for D7 (not sure about D6) you can add a field of type "Math expression" to do this sort of thing.  Enter the expression `[!1]+1` (or maybe `[%1]+1`) in the Math expression field, and then later text fields can refer to this value (in their Rewrite sections) as `[expression]`.

Answer (score 0):

[Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) normally be my answer, but it appears that it doesn't [support PHP in Contextual Filters](http://drupal.org/project/issues/views_php?text=contextual&status=All) quite yet...

So you'll need to create yourself a module and then:

- Implement [`hook_views_api()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) to tell Views your module wants to use its API - see: [How do I use hook_views_query_alter()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/how-do-i-use-hook-views-query-alter)
- Implement [`hook_views_query_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) then do something like this:

  ```
  function YOURMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    if ($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
       $query->where[0]['conditions'][0] += $value; // change this line accordingly
    }
  }
  ```

I'm assuming your first argument is the one you want to change, and I don't have a view I can test against right now, so you'll need to `print_r(`$query->where[0]);` to see what's going on in there and add to the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  $arg = $view -> args[0];
  $newarg = intval($arg) + 1;
?>
<a href="/view2/<?php print($newarg); ?>">Increment my contextual filter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create views template for your views and do something like this below.

```
<?php $arg = arg(1);  ?>
<a href="<?php print base_path() . 'view2/' . ($arg + 1) ;?>">Link to view</a>
```