# How to alter view query

Tags: views, 7, hooks

I am just looking for altering select query, created by any view just before its execute. For e.g. I want to add some manual filter which I can't add from Views' UI.

Comment: use hook_views_query_alter() to alter the select query.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking to use [`hook_view_query_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7), additionally you might want to look into some related questions on Drupal answers [How do I use hook_views_query_alter()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/how-do-i-use-hook-views-query-alter).