# How to implement hook_views_query_alter?

Tags: hooks, views

I used [this topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/how-do-i-use-hook-views-query-alter) before asking question but even if the problem is very very closed, the answers given did not work for me.

So I need to alter the query of one of my views in drupal 7. I created a new module called for example 'mymodule'. This module contains

- .info file.
- .module file.
- .views.inc file.

My **.module file** contains the following. Note that my **.views.inc** file is located at the root of the module directory. I also checked that my views api version is 3 :

```
function modulename_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename'),
  );
}
```

My **.views.inc file**, which is at the root of the module directory contains the following :

```
function modulename_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
dpm($view);
watchdog('error title', 'error message');
echo 'TEST TEST';
die('test');
if ($view->name == 'my_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'my_display_name') {
    unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][0]);
    unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][1]);
 }
}
```

I can't see what I am missing trying to implement this hook but it never go into the views_query_alter function (I cleared the cache before trying). I think I've followed all advices given in the link provided above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmmm maybe you need to clear cache in admin/config/development/performance

Comment: I already did it !

Comment: Have you enabled the module? Code looks fine to me

Comment: You killed me, I "just" forget to enable the module...Sorry for the unuseful post, I'm still a beginner in Drupal and miss some basic reflex.

Answer (score 0):

.views.inc file is to separate the views alter logic.

[hook_views_api](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) to add the mymodule.views.inc file which can be with path your-module/includes/views or at the root of your module.

You also can use mymodule_views_query_alter at mymodule.module file which should work fine.

Please remove the cache after applying the changes.